# Image Uri does not appear in XAML

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I don't understand the problem : I have a link of an image but it does not visible :

```
<Image Source="http://www.bestofleboncoin.fr/img/adsok/thumbs/304409998.jpg" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
```

if I download this picture and save it in the solution it's ok !

```
<Image Source="/304409998.jpg" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
```

If I upload on my personal website, this image is visible too..

Comment: Wait, when do you have the problem? When you have it locally or when it is on your personal website or when it is on that particular site?

Comment: When I use this Uri http://www.bestofleboncoin.fr/img/adsok/thumbs/304409998.jpg. (I read it on a RSS feed)

Comment: And you are sure that it starts with `http://`? Maybe that is the problem. How do you set that uri in your code?

Comment: I read this uri from this RSS : http://www.bestofleboncoin.fr/f/rss-20.xml

Answer (score 1):

Can you download it using `WebClient` and then display it inside your control? Besides, you are supposed to just that for performance reasons.

It appears as if the site in question forbids direct linking.

Answer (score 0):

I have a little solution but I don't know about performances ....

```
  <phone:WebBrowser Name="Browser" Source="{Binding Links[1].Uri}"  />
```